# I need pop up numpad in every input field.. using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an input field and a button, whenever user clicks on input field numpad pop up will comes. and I have used loop to create extra input fields. when i click first input field popup will come but when i click on second ,third input filed its not showing pop up.

basic html below...

```
          <input  type="text" id="demo-numpad-1" maxlength="6"/>

          <button class="button" onclick="add_fields()">Add</button>
              <div id="room_fileds">
                 //here i am creating input fields.
              </div>
```

below is my function

```
          var room = 1;
        function add_fields() {
            room++;
            var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds')
            var divtest = document.createElement("div");
            if(room <=6){
            divtest.innerHTML = ' <br/>  <input  type="text" id="demo-numpad-'+room+'" 
         maxlength="6"/>  ';
             objTo.appendChild(divtest)
          }
        }
```

below is popup numpad it uses id for popup

```
              window.addEventListener("load", function(){
                // Bare minimum - provide the ID
                numpad.attach({
                  id : "demo-numpad-1",
                  readonly : false, 
                  // Allow decimal points? True by default
                  decimal : false,
                  // Maximum allowed characters, 16 by default
                  // Feel free to modify the script to set a maximum allowed number instead
                  max : 6

                });
           numpad.attach({
                  id : "demo-numpad-2",
                  readonly : false, 
                  // Allow decimal points? True by default
                  decimal : false,
                  // Maximum allowed characters, 16 by default
                  // Feel free to modify the script to set a maximum allowed number instead
                  max : 6

                });
           numpad.attach({
                  id : "demo-numpad-3",
                  readonly : false, 
                  // Allow decimal points? True by default
                  decimal : false,
                  // Maximum allowed characters, 16 by default
                  // Feel free to modify the script to set a maximum allowed number instead
                  max : 6

                });..
                  });
```

i have another js file for popup numpad below ...

```
                var numpad = {
                /* [INIT - DRAW THE ON-SCREEN NUMPAD] */
                selector : null, // will hold the entire on-screen numpad
                display : null, // will hold the numpad display
                zero : null, // will hold the zero button
                dot : null, // will hold the dot button
                init : function () {
                  // CREATE THE NUMPAD
                  numpad.selector = document.createElement("div");
                  numpad.selector.id = "numpad-back";
                  var wrap = document.createElement("div");
                  wrap.id = "numpad-wrap";
                  numpad.selector.appendChild(wrap);

                  // ATTACH THE NUMBER DISPLAY
                  numpad.display = document.createElement("input");
                  numpad.display.id = "numpad-display";
                  numpad.display.type = "text";
                  numpad.display.readOnly = true;
                  wrap.appendChild(numpad.display);

                  // ATTACH BUTTONS
                  var buttons = document.createElement("div"),
                      button = null,
                      append = function (txt, fn, css) {
                        button = document.createElement("div");
                        button.innerHTML = txt;
                        button.classList.add("numpad-btn");
                        if (css) {
                          button.classList.add(css);
                        }
                        button.addEventListener("click", fn);
                        buttons.appendChild(button);
                      };
                  buttons.id = "numpad-btns";
                  // First row - 7 to 9, delete.
                  for (var i=7; i<=9; i++) {
                    append(i, numpad.digit);
                  }
                  append("&#10502;", numpad.delete, "ng");
                  // Second row - 4 to 6, clear.
                  for (var i=4; i<=6; i++) {
                    append(i, numpad.digit);
                  }
                  append("C", numpad.reset, "ng");
                  // Third row - 1 to 3, cancel.
                  for (var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
                    append(i, numpad.digit);
                  }
                  append("&#10006;", numpad.hide, "cx");
                  // Last row - 0, dot, ok
                  append(0, numpad.digit, "zero");
                  numpad.zero = button;
                  append(".", numpad.dot);
                  numpad.dot = button;
                  append("&#10004;", numpad.select, "ok");
                  // Add all buttons to wrapper
                  wrap.appendChild(buttons);
                  document.body.appendChild(numpad.selector);
                },

                /* [ATTACH TO INPUT] */
                attach : function (opt) {
                // attach() : attach numpad to target input field

                  var target = document.getElementById(opt.id);
                  if (target!=null) {
                    // APPEND DEFAULT OPTIONS
                    if (opt.readonly==undefined || typeof opt.readonly!="boolean") { opt.readonly = true; }
                    if (opt.decimal==undefined || typeof opt.decimal!="boolean") { opt.decimal = true; }
                    if (opt.max==undefined || typeof opt.max!="number") { opt.max = 16; }

                    // SET READONLY ATTRIBUTE ON TARGET FIELD
                    if (opt.readonly) { target.readOnly = true; }

                    // ALLOW DECIMALS?
                    target.dataset.decimal = opt.decimal ? 1 : 0;

                    // MAXIMUM ALLOWED CHARACTERS
                    target.dataset.max = opt.max;

                    // SHOW NUMPAD ON CLICK
                    target.addEventListener("click", numpad.show);
                  } else {
                    console.log(opt.id + " NOT FOUND!");
                  }
                },

                target : null, // contains the current selected field
                dec : true, // allow decimals?
                max : 16, // max allowed characters
                show : function (evt) {
                // show() : show the number pad

                  // Set current target field
                  numpad.target = evt.target;

                  // Show or hide the decimal button
                  numpad.dec = numpad.target.dataset.decimal==1;
                  if (numpad.dec) {
                    numpad.zero.classList.remove("zeroN");
                    numpad.dot.classList.remove("ninja");
                  } else {
                    numpad.zero.classList.add("zeroN");
                    numpad.dot.classList.add("ninja");
                  }

                  // Max allowed characters
                  numpad.max = parseInt(numpad.target.dataset.max);

                  // Set display value
                  var dv = evt.target.value;
                  if (!isNaN(parseFloat(dv)) && isFinite(dv)) {
                    numpad.display.value = dv;
                  } else {
                    numpad.display.value = "";
                  }

                  // Show numpad
                  numpad.selector.classList.add("show");
                },

                hide : function () {
                // hide() : hide the number pad

                  numpad.selector.classList.remove("show");
                },

                /* [BUTTON ONCLICK ACTIONS] */
                delete : function () {
                // delete() : delete last digit on the number pad

                  var length = numpad.display.value.length;
                  if (length > 0) {
                    numpad.display.value = numpad.display.value.substring(0, length-1);
                  }
                },

                reset : function () {
                // reset() : reset the number pad

                  numpad.display.value = "";
                },

                digit : function (evt) {
                // digit() : append a digit

                  var current = numpad.display.value,
                      append = evt.target.innerHTML;

                  if (current.length < numpad.max) {
                    if (current=="0") {
                      numpad.display.value = append;
                    } else {
                      numpad.display.value += append;
                    }
                  }
                },

                dot : function () {
                // dot() : add the decimal point (only if not already appended)

                  if (numpad.display.value.indexOf(".") == -1) {
                    if (numpad.display.value=="") {
                      numpad.display.value = "0.";
                    } else {
                      numpad.display.value += ".";
                    }
                  }
                },

                select : function () {
                // select() : select the current number

                  var value = numpad.display.value;

                  // No decimals allowed - strip decimal
                  if (!numpad.dec && value%1!=0) {
                    value = parseInt(value);
                  }

                  // Put selected value to target field + close numpad
                  numpad.target.value = value;
                  numpad.hide();
                }
              };

              /* [INIT] */
              window.addEventListener("load", numpad.init);
```

Comment: You're attaching all demo-numpad items to numpad on page load, but those items doesn't exist yet. So, you must attach them after creating them.

Comment: bro ,i am not getting, please tell me what  to modify in above code...

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put this at the bottom of your `add_fields` function right after `objTo.appendChild(divtest)`:

```
numpad.attach({
   id : "demo-numpad-" + room,
   readonly : false,
   decimal : false,
   max : 6
});
```

Also you should only have one call to `numpad.attach` inside onload event because you only have one input.

Comment: Yes, I know. What I mean is that onload event just run once at the beggining, after that numpad.attach should be called for each new input and that should happen when you click the button (add_fields function).